# passing dynamically created comma separated values in a string to 'in' clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pass a comma separated values in a variable to the select statement but I am not getting the result.

Here is the **SQL**:

```
DECLARE @dataCodes XML = '<Root>
                    <List Value="120" />
                    <List Value="110" />
                </Root>';      

DECLARE @ConcatString VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ',','') + Code
FROM (
    SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
    FROM @dataCodes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item)
    ) as TBL

SET @ConcatString=''''+REPLACE(@ConcatString,',',''',''') +'''';

SELECT NAME, ID, ROLE from MyTable where CODE in (@ConcatString); -- not working
```

**Output of @ConcatString**

[image]

**Note:**

If I pass the values directly as shown below, I am able to see the result,

```
SELECT NAME, ID, ROLE from MyTable where CODE in ('110','120');
```

I am trying this because, my SQL structure is something like:

```
 WITH JMATRIX_RESULT AS(      
       SELECT DISTINCT  ... from MyTable1 where CODE in (@ConcatString)
UNION
       SELECT DISTINCT  ... from MyTable2 where CODE in (@ConcatString)
UNION 
       SELECT DISTINCT  ... from MyTable3 where CODE in (@ConcatString)
),
...
```

and I see performance improvement when passing the parameter as comma separated values.

**Expectation:**

If I pass the dynamically created comma separated values in string (@ConcatString) to the in clause of select statement, it should return the values.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: what is the data type of code

Comment: datatype of code is VARCHAR

Comment: you have to create dynamic query then execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you concatenating the string simply do the following :

```
DECLARE @dataCodes XML = '<Root>
                            <List Value="120" />
                            <List Value="110" />
                          </Root>'; 


SELECT NAME, ID, ROLE 
from MyTable 
where CODE in (
                SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
                FROM @dataCodes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item)
               );
```

Comment: My original code was like this but, I am having performance issue and I observed that replacing the current select statement within the 'in' clause with comma separated string increased the performance significantly. I have updated the question with my SQL Structure and I hope it gives the idea.

Comment: I am staying with the same code, which is the solution you have suggested.